# awk how to find first available date field?

Tags: bash, awk

```
Fields 1,2,3,4 are date fields yyyy-mm-dd. 
Delimited by ";"
"-" if no date.
Field 4 will always have a date
```

Examples;

```
-; 2016-08-19; 2016-08-19; 2018-07-17; Beach-Rangiroa.jpg
-; -; -; 2018-09-12; MV3_0034-copy.webp
2016-12-10; 2016-12-10; 2016-12-20; 2018-07-18; Sukhothai-61.jpg
-; -; -; 2018-07-19; Gdu9Rwhu6W3Q5W6q_1Qag.jpg
```

**Objective**: Use awk to print the 1st available date in order fields 1,2,3,4

I've tried this;

```
awk -F";" '{if ($1!="-") print $1; else if ($2!="-") print $2; else if ($3!="-") prin$3; else if ($4!="-") print $4}'
```

Results...

```
 2016-08-19
 -
 -
```

bash version 4.3.48

I am trying to achieve this: e.g. line 1 in example...

2016-08-19; Beach-Rangiroa.jpg

```
echo '-; -; -; 2018-07-15; Stock-Photo-114398301.webp; WEBP; image/webp; 2000; 1333' | \
awk -F';' 'OFS=";" {for(i=1; i<5; ++i) { if ($i ~ /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{,2}-[0-9]{,2}/) { print $i,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9; next; }}}'
```

Result;

2018-07-15; Stock-Photo-114398301.webp; WEBP; image/webp; 2000; 1333

This works nicely, except the 1st space on the date, also is there a method available to verify the date, e.g. date -d "%Y-%m-%d" ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you clean up your question to get rid of all the edits and just tell us **the question** with **the sample input/output** it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gnu only `gawk` solution using `FPAT`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{,2}-[0-9]{,2}"}{print $1}' file1
2016-08-19
2018-09-12
2018-07-19
```

With `FPAT` you actually instruct `gawk` what to consider as a field, a whole regex here. If the input line has also a second date this will appear as `$2`, `$NF` will return the last date field of each line,`NF` will return the total date fields,and so on.

Comment: There's no FPAT in awk. Perhaps you're using gawk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable for field numbers:

```
awk -F\; '{for(i=1; i<5; ++i) { if ($i ~ /[0-9]/) { print $i; next; }}}' in
```

Comment: Should be `-F' *; *'` to trim the date value. `FS` is a full regular expression, according to the man page. You can also set the `i < NF` for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without awk:
You said you wanted the 1st available date. When you only want 1 line output, you can use

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" inputfile| head -1
```

When you want to have the first date for each line, change the `grep` or use `sed`:

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*" inputfile| cut -d';' -f1
# or
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/; s/.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/\1/' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all for your help.

I think this acomplishes the objective;

```
echo '-; -; -; 2018-07-25; Redwood-Forest-Sequoia-4.jpg; JPEG; image/jpeg; 1280; 720' | \
awk -F'; ' 'OFS="; " {for(i=1; i<5; ++i) { if ($i ~ /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{,2}-[0-9]{,2}/) { print $i,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9; next; }}}'
```

Result;

```
2018-07-25; Redwood-Forest-Sequoia-4.jpg; JPEG; image/jpeg; 1280; 720
```

Best regards.